# How to re-evaluate state of checkbutton in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter, ttk

I can't seem to re-evaluate the state of a checkbox. In a simple explination, I can do the following

```
import tkinter
from tkinter imprt ttk
root = Tk()
ck = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Checkbox')
ck.state(['!alternate'])
ck.state(['selected'])

if ck.instate(['selected']):
    # do something
elif ck.instate(['!selected']):
    # do something else

root.mainloop()
```

This sets the checkbutton to a 'selected' state, and then runs the `if` statement because it is selected. However, if I were to unselect that checkbox, it doesn't re-evaluate the state of the checkbox and run the `elif` statement. I've looked at things like `root.update()` or `root.update_idletasks`, but I'm fairly certain this isn't what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help!

As a side note, I'm on Python 3.x

Comment: this `if/else` is executed only once - at start. If you have to execute something during running program then assign/bind function to `Checkbutton`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if/else` is executed only once - at start. If you have to execute something during running program then assign function to `Checkbutton`

```
 ttk.Checkbutton( ..., command=function_name)
```

and it will be execute when you click checkbutton

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def clicked():
    if ck.instate(['selected']):
        print('selected')
    elif ck.instate(['!selected']):
        print('not selected')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

ck = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Checkbox', command=clicked)
ck.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: probably only `Button` and `Checkbutton` have `command=` - other widgets need `widget.bind(event_type, function_name)` - ie. `root.bind('<Key>', on_keypress)`